# Whitelisting a IPv6

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

On top of my broadband package I'm paying a little bit extra for having a static IP.
I was wondering for a long time why I cannot access our office network despite my IPs being whitelisted. To be more precise, after my IP being whitelisted, I could access the office network for a few days but then again the connection was refused.

I found out that while my IPv4 remains always the same, my IPv6 is changing frequently.

It turned out that by a static IPv6, only the first half of the IPv6 address which is being assigned by the ISP is static and the second part is being obtained by the computer itself and get changed from time to time.

For example this was the IPv6 on my laptop a fews days ago:

**1234:5678:4321:8765:c084:b043:273d:cdf8**

And this is the one from today:

**1234:5678:4321:8765:6449:7bfe:9ddd:afab**

As yo can see the first half (1234:5678:4321:8765) is the same but the the second half is changed.

After some googling I read somewhere that to whitelist every possible combination of a static IPv6 address from:

1234:5678:4321:8765:0:0:0:0

To:

1234:5678:4321:8765:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

You can use this CIDR mask:

**1234:5678:4321:8765:0:0:0:0/64**

The above is still my static IP (1234:5678:4321:8765) but will cover all possible combination of it.

Is the above statement correct?

I also asked my ISP and they told me that my static IPv6 address is this one:

**1234:5678:4321:8765::/56**

If the above statement is correct, which of the following IPv6 should be whitelisted?

- 1234:5678:4321:8765::/56
- 1234:5678:4321:8765::/64
- 1234:5678:4321:8765:0:0:0:0/64

Comment: You _can_ disable the Privacy Extensions with Random Addresses on your PC. How you do that varies by OS. Then you would have the same IPv6 address every time.

Answer (score 2):

`/64` is the smallest possible subnet in IPv6 as defined [RFC 5375](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5375/). So it's not uncommon for ISPs to assign clients `/56` subnets so clients will be able to easily split their networks into256 `/64` subnets.

So if the ISP assigned you a (static) `/56`, you can probably whitelist the entire `/56` range.

As a side note `1234:5678:4321:8765::/64` and `1234:5678:4321:8765:0:0:0:0/64` are the same thing. The `::` stands for a sequence of zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be sure, it would be enough to whitelist this one, right? 1234:5678:4321:8765::/56

Comment: yeah, that should be enough